# Monaca for Visual Studioで日本語が文字化けする

Tags: monaca, 文字化け

Monaca for Visual Studioで日本語をソースコードに記述すると文字化けしてしまいます。
ブラウザ上で行う分には問題ありませんでした。

以下ソース

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

### page1.html

```html
<ons-page>
    <html>
    <body>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">test</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <div style="text-align: center">

            <br>
            <ons-button onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html')">
            日本語テスト
            </ons-button>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Monaca for Visual Studioは使用経験がありませんが、通常Visual Studioでは「ソリューション エクスプローラー」でファイルを右クリックし、「ファイルを開くアプリケーションの選択」で「エンコード付き○○」というエディターを選べばファイルの文字コードを指定できます。

Answer (score 0):

保存時の文字エンコーディングがUTF-8以外に設定されている可能性があります。
保存時に「名前を付けて保存」を選択していただき、「上書き保存」ではなく

「Unicode(UTF-8シグネチャなし) - コードページ65001」

を指定してみてください。

Answer (score -2):

Shift_JISで文字化けなくなりました

Comment: あなたの環境ではそれで解決したという情報提供でしょうか？何をShift_JISにしたら改善したのか、回答を[edit]して追記していただけるとより参考になると思います。